# Cat vomiting and not acting right

Tags: cats, behavior, health

I have a Bengal at home. The other day I fed him some raw chicken that was sitting in the fridge and I just took out to season and prepare. The next morning I woke up and there were piles of dry vomit in a few places. The cat was not being 100% himself. The next day I came home and noticed that he didn't go potty nor did he eat much of his food. I fed the cat some snacks, but he threw that up as well. He's been drinking water, but he doesn't seem to be groomed (which he always does).

What can be an issue here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take him to a vet **ASAP**.

You should not feed animals raw food, especially chicken.
He might have a food poisoning or worse.

If he has a fever, he can die from this.

Comment: pancreatic discomfort

Comment: Fixed the strikeouts to be standard edits. Feel free to make it bold again if you really feel that's necssary. There are legitimate ways to serve raw food, but you need to be _at least_ as careful as when preparing a raw fish for humans -- possibly more so. If you want to feed your cat sushi or steak tartare, it needs to be handled with care. If you want to feed the cat chicken.... the risks are probably excessive unless you are either raising the birds yourself or are using one of the fancier sterilization techniques like irradiation, which are effectively a form of cooking.

Comment: Really? I heard that a little bit of raw chicken is fine for cats. https://kb.rspca.org.au/knowledge-base/what-should-i-feed-my-cat/

Answer (score 2):

Raw food *can* be prepared properly for a cat, but unless you have researched how, it is not a good idea. Nor should it be done with raw foods you have just lying around. Most likely, he had food poisoning and needs a vet ASAP.

It is also possible the cat is allergic to chicken; as odd as that sounds, it does happen, and if so he also needs a vet ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Your cat is repeatedly vomiting, and his behavior suggests he is not comfortable. These are clear signs that there is something wrong with him, and he should be taken to a vet asap.

You can try feeling his ears: if they are unusually warm, he has a fever—another sign you need to take him to the vet.

If there is anything you suspect might be related (such as the food you fed him), do mention it to the vet.